# Angular 7. ngx-material-timepicker, toggle button not properly aligned

Tags: angular, angular-material, timepicker

I am using [ngx-material-timepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-material-timepicker) to create date and time pickers.

Here is the relevant part of my template. (I have no extra css for the component)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <mat-form-field>
        <input
          matInput
          [matDatepicker]="picker"
          placeholder="Choose a date"
          [min]="minDate"
          [(ngModel)]="chosenDate"
          (ngModelChange)="dateChanged()"
        />
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <mat-form-field>
        <input
          matInput
          [ngxTimepicker]="timePick"
          placeholder="Chose time"
          [min]="minTime"
          [(ngModel)]="chosenTime"
          (ngModelChange)="timeChanged()"
        />
        <ngx-material-timepicker-toggle
          [for]="timePick"
        ></ngx-material-timepicker-toggle>
        <ngx-material-timepicker
          [defaultTime]="minTime"
          #timePick
        ></ngx-material-timepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The result is this:

[image]

The date picker is working just fine, but the toggle button for the time picker is not aligned as it should be. I have followed the [official documentation](https://agranom.github.io/ngx-material-timepicker/)

How to align the clock like the calendar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to wrap `input` and `toggle-button` in `div` and set `display: flex` to that `div`. Something like this:

```
<div>
  <input>
  <ngx-material-timepicker-toggle></ngx-material-timepicker-toggle>
</div>
```

Css:

```
div { display:flex }
```

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem too, but all you have to do is add `MatSuffix` to the `ngx-material-timepicker-toggle` and it will correctly align the button.

```
<ngx-material-timepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="timePick" ></ngx-material-timepicker-toggle>
```

Comment: @Brent with ```matSuffix``` how can I reduce the size of the icon like of Material Datepicker

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you're using `<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" />`

to resolve this problem, as Виталик Бойко suggested wrap both in a div and apply `div { display:flex }`

Also, use change the height of the time picker

CSS

`::ng-deep .ngx-timepicker {
  height: 72% !important;
}`